# Does this random sequence converge almost surely or in distribution?

Tags: random-variable, convergence

In professor Leon Garcia's textbook "Probability, Statistics and Random Processes for Electrical Engineering"
there is an example (example 7.20 on page 383) of almost sure convergence of a random sequence.

> An urn contains 2 black balls and 2 white balls.At time n a ball is
> selected at random from the urn, and the color is noted. If the number
> of balls of this color is greater than the number of balls of the
> other color, then the ball is put back in the urn; otherwise, the ball
> is left out. Let be $X_n(\zeta)$ the number of black balls in the urn
> after the nth draw. Does this sequence of random variables converge?

The answer given in the book is:

> The first draw is the critical draw. Suppose the first draw is black,
> then the black ball that is selected will be left out. Thereafter,
> each time a white ball is selected it will be put back in, and when
> the remaining black ball is selected it will be left out. Thus with
> probability one, the black ball will eventually be selected, and
> $X_n(\zeta)$ will converge to zero. On the other hand, if a white ball
> is selected in the first draw, then eventually the remaining white
> ball will be removed, and hence with probability one $X_n(\zeta)$ will
> converge to zero. Thus $X_n(\zeta) $is equally likely to eventually
> converge to 0 or 2, that is,

$$
X_n(\zeta) \rightarrow X(\zeta)~~~\text{as } n \rightarrow \infty~~\text{almost surely}
$$
where
$$
P[X(\zeta)=0]=P[X(\zeta)=2]=\frac{1}{2}
$$

But isn't it wrong? Because although $X_n$ behaves more and more like a Bernoulli random variable
as n increases, we can not find a Bernoulli random variable $X$ that satisfies the definition of almost sure convergence:
$$
P[\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |X_n - X| < \epsilon] = 1
$$

Since $X_n$ and $X$ are independent, $P[\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |X_n - X| < \epsilon] = 1/2$ for any arbitrarily small $\epsilon$. So I think the answer should be "the random sequence converges in distribution". Or am I wrong?

Comment: Sounds like there will be no black or no white balls eventually. If this interpretation is correct, then the convergence is a.s. Your argument does not work since the limit and the sequence need not be independent for a.s. convergence.

Comment: according to the procedure of the experiment, with probability one, there will be only black balls or white balls in the long run.

Comment: OK, then with probability one $X_n$ will behave like $X$ for large $n$. So the convergence is a.s. Does this clarify?

Comment: with probability one $X_n$  will behave like X  for large n: This matches the definition of convergence **in distribution** I suppose.

Comment: I would recommend you look up the definitions again. The fact that it happens with probability one is decisive here

Comment: Then suppose $X_n$ is a $n$th Bernoulli random variable. As n increases, $X_n$ behaves "more and more like" a Bernoulli random variable. 
Actually every $X_n$ **is** a Bernoulli random variable. In this case can we say $X_n$ converges to $X$ (an arbitrary Bernoulli random variable) almost surely.? I don't think so. 
$X_n$ converges to $X$ **in distribution**.  This same logic applies to the example in the question.